# Question for Ruby Gurus (help with Enum-like implementation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a sort of "enum". Here is my implementation:

```
# Format of input hash to AnEnum::initialize is :
# {
#   Symbol => [Fixnum => String]
# }
# Example:
# {
#   :active => [1 => "Active"]
# }

class AnEnum
  @@values = nil
  def initialize(hash)
    @@values = hash
  end

  def values
    @@values
  end

  def [](symbol)
    values[symbol][0] # return the number for the symbol. e.g. 1
  end

  def text(symbol)
    values[symbol][1] # return the text for the symbol. e.g. "Active"
  end
end
```

Example Usage:

```
class MyClass1

  @@status = AnEnum.new({
      :open => [1, 'Active'],
      :closed => [2, 'Closed']
    })

  def self.Status
    @@status
  end      

end

# test it (it works!)

MyClass1.Status[:open] # => 1
MyClass1.Status.text(:open) # => "Active"
```

This works, but I want to make it more "elegant" and "dynamic" :

Is it possible to define `AnEnum` in `MyClass2` like this:

```
class MyClass2
  define_enum "Status", :as => {
    :open => [1, 'Active'],
    :closed => [2, 'Closed']
  }
end
```

So that these will work:

```
MyClass2.Status[:open] # => 1
MyClass2.Status.text(:open) # => "Active"
```

Thus, the `@@status` and `self.Status` defined in `MyClass1` above are automatically included in the class by the "macro"-like call to `define_enum`.

`define_enum` is intended to be working like for example the `before_filter` call in Rails.

Is this possible??

Comment: The "Question for Ruby Gurus" part doesn't provide any useful information. The tag indicates that it's ruby, everything on SO ought to be a question, and saying you only want gurus is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's great if you're tackling this problem for your own personal gain, however if it's because you actually need this functionality, there are tons of Ruby gems out there that already do this. If you need each "State" to exhibit different behavior, I have written a useful gem called [classy_enum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum). Otherwise, [here are a ton of others](https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=ruby&q=enum&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1).

To answer your question though, yes it is definitely possible to add class methods or macros as you are describing. A high level overview would look something like:

```
module MyEnum
  def define_enum(name, states)
    ... meta code here ...
  end
end
```

Then in your class:

```
MyClass
  extend MyEnum

  define_enum :name, :state1 => [], :state2 => []
end
```

The "meta code" is where it gets tricky depending on what you are trying to do. If you are going to go this route, I would still recommend checking out how others have done it first. You've got a few things in your example that are a little odd, such as capitalized method names (`def self.Status`) and class variables `@@my_var`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?id=184 (slight improvement over http://www.rubyfleebie.com/enumerations-and-ruby/). Lets you write the following.

```
class Gender
  include Enum

  Gender.define :MALE, "male"
  Gender.define :FEMALE, "female"
end
```

And of course

```
Gender.all
Gender::MALE
```